# Test Class for Trigger is not providing coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have created a trigger that makes a field a value based on certain criteria. I have the trigger written and I have the test class, however for some reason I only get 29% code coverage when run the test class.

**Class**

```
trigger CommissionUpdate on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {
    for(Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new{
        if(newOpp.LeadSource.equals('Self Generated')){
            if(newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=0 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <35){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 0;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=35 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c < 40){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (5/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <45){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (8/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=45 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (8/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=50 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <60){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (11/100)*100;    
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=60 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <70){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (12/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=70 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (13/100)*100;         
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (13/100)*100; 
            }

      }else{
             if(newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=0 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <35){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 0;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=35 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c < 40){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (2/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <45){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (3.5/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=45 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (3.5/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=50 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <60){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (5.5/100)*100;    
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=60 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <70){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (6.50/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=70 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (7.0/100)*100;         
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (7.5/100)*100; 
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TestCommissionUpdate{
    static testmethod void insertOpportunity(){

    Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
    newOpp.Name = 'test opp';
    newOpp.Type = 'New Business';
    newOpp.CloseDate = date.today();
    newOpp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    newOpp.LeadSource = 'Self Generated';
    newOpp.Trade_Show_Name__c = 'Fake Trade Show';
    newOpp.City__c = 'Fake City';
    newOpp.State__c ='Fake State';
    newOpp.Subtotal__c = 660.00;
    newOpp.Tax__c = 39.60;
    newOpp.Purchases__c = 384;
    insert newOpp;   



    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a trigger for this, check out workflow/process builder.

Comment: I know how to do it in workflow however, the compiled code is over 5,00 0 characters. It comes out to 22,000 characters since it depends on so many other fields that are formulas.

Comment: FYI, you could have reduced this trigger to about 10 lines of code with Custom Metadata or Custom Settings.

Comment: How would I be able to do that? I'm not very experienced with apex programming

Comment: @Alias311 Actually, I just realized that most of your calculations are invalid. For example, (8/100)*100 results in a final value of 0. You should review how you're performing your calculations.

Comment: How would that result in "0". (8/100) = 0.8 that times 100 is equal to 8

Comment: How has no one mentioned **[smoke testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software))** yet!? You ***must add assertions to properly unit test your code***.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Lol cause I am just seeing this now :)

Answer (score 3):

All you need is just this simple formula for your `Commission_Real__c` field:

```
CASE( FLOOR(Mark_Up_Real__c / 10),
 7, IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 13, 7),
 6, IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 12, 6.5),
 5, IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 11, 5.5),
 4, IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 8, 3.5),
 IF( Mark_Up_Real__c >= 80,
  IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 13, 7.5),
  IF( Mark_Up_Real__c >= 35,
    IF(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, 'Self Generated'), 5, 2),
    0
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Formula does not require unit tests. +1

Comment: I had something similar to this however when compiling the number of characters is greater than 5,000.  The compiled code is 6,335 characters.

Comment: What is your formula for `Mark_Up_Real__c`?

Comment: You can move the `ISPICKVAL` check to before your `CASE` statement to just evaluate it once. You could even just do `CASE(IF(ISPICKVAL(/*source*/), 10, 0) + FLOOR(/*markup*/), 17, 13, 7, 7, 16, 12, 6, 6.5, etc)` and only need to evaluate both source and markup once.

Comment: my formula for Mark_Up_Real__c is (Profit_Real__c/Cost_Real__c), both Profit_Real__c and Cost_Real__c are formula fields.

Comment: Try my updated formula if it's under 5K characters. You can also provide your `Profit_Real__c` and `Cost_Real__c` formulas to see if they can be simplified. The problem is that every time you include another formula field in your formula, it will add up to the compiled size its length

Answer (score 2):

The trigger logic seems to update the existing record with the commissions data and not create a new record. The trigger should fire on Before insert & update.

In the test data you should have multiple functions which will have different values for newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c, lead source is 'Self Generated' and also when lead source is not 'Self Generated' so that all your if else conditions are covered.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense let me try that. Can I add if statements in the test class?

Comment: You can have if statements in the test class but here you need to create different set of data for each of your if else scenarios in different test methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem your code has is that you have to test **every condition**. That is for **self generated** opps and **other lead source opps**. And test for every percentage.

**Trigger**

```
trigger CommissionUpdate on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {
    OpportunityTriggerController objController = null;

    objController = new OpportunityTriggerController();
    objController.updateComissions(Trigger.new);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class OpportunityTriggerController {
    public void updateComissions(List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity ) {
        Map<Integer,Decimal> mapPercentage = null;

        if(lstOpportunity != null && lstOpportunity.size() > 0) {
            for(Opportunity objOpportuniy : lstOpportunity)  { 
                if(objOpportuniy.LeadSource.equals('Self Generated')){ 
                    mapPercentage = retrieveComissionMapGenerated();
                } else {
                    mapPercentage = retrieveComissionMapOther();            
                }

                for(Integer intComissionIndex : mapPercentage.keySet()) {
                    if(objOpportuniy.Mark_Up_Real__c >= intComissionIndex ) {
                        objOpportuniy.Commission_Real__c = mapPercentage.get(intComissionIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    private Map<Integer,Decimal> retrieveComissionMapGenerated() {
        Map<Integer,Decimal> mapPercentage = null;
        mapPercentage = new Map<Integer,Decimal>();
        mapPercentage.put(70,13);
        mapPercentage.put(60,12);
        mapPercentage.put(50,11);
        mapPercentage.put(40,8);
        mapPercentage.put(35,5);

        return mapPercentage;
    }

    private Map<Integer,Decimal> retrieveComissionMapOther() {
        Map<Integer,Decimal> mapPercentage = null;
        mapPercentage = new Map<Integer,Decimal>();
        mapPercentage.put(80,7.5);
        mapPercentage.put(70,7);
        mapPercentage.put(60,6.5);
        mapPercentage.put(50,5.5);
        mapPercentage.put(40,3.5);  
        mapPercentage.put(35,2);

        return mapPercentage;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class TestComissionUpdate{
    @isTest     
    static void insertOpportunitySelfGenerated(){
        Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
            newOpp.Name = 'test opp';
            newOpp.Type = 'New Business';
            newOpp.CloseDate = date.today();
            newOpp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
            newOpp.LeadSource = 'Self Generated';
            newOpp.Trade_Show_Name__c = 'Fake Trade Show';
            newOpp.City__c = 'Fake City';
            newOpp.State__c ='Fake State';
            newOpp.Subtotal__c = 660.00;
            newOpp.Tax__c = 39.60;
            newOpp.Purchases__c = 384;
            insert newOpp;
    }
    @isTest     
    static void insertOpportunityOther(){
        Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
            newOpp.Name = 'test opp';
            newOpp.Type = 'New Business';
            newOpp.CloseDate = date.today();
            newOpp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
            newOpp.LeadSource = 'Other';
            newOpp.Trade_Show_Name__c = 'Fake Trade Show';
            newOpp.City__c = 'Fake City';
            newOpp.State__c ='Fake State';
            newOpp.Subtotal__c = 660.00;
            newOpp.Tax__c = 39.60;
            newOpp.Purchases__c = 384;
            insert newOpp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I ran your code and the test class failed but the code did cover all 3 lines at 100%.

Comment: This code does not suppose to work. I havent your enviroment. Like Morpheus said : I’m trying to free your mind, Neo. But I can only show you the door. You’re the one that has to walk through it.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for guiding me into the right direction.

Comment: You can also put the comission values into a Custom Setting. I would be even better.  You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

First off, your logic is flawed. As @sfdcfox pointed (8/100)*100 equals to zero because you're doing this with Integers. 8 divided by 100 (using Integers) will be equal to 0. After this you can multiply 0 with what you want but it will return zero. If you want to get decimal point then you should use Decimals. So your code should (8.0/100)*100 and this will be equal to 8.0. Also if all your calculations will be return what you are trying to divide (thinking in decimals) so (3.5/100)*100 will result 3.5 so on so forth... Also you have some repeating logic. For example;

```
  }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <45){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (8/100)*100;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=45 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = (8/100)*100;
```

why not just write;

```
}else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 8;
  }
```

And this repeats on several occasions.

@Oleksiy answers cover what you need. It's best to not write code when you can do it with clicks. If you write code now when there is a change in your logic you need to fix your code then change your test to get coverage. Then test in sandbox and finally deploy it to prod. It's best to keep this kind of customization in workflows/process builder to maintain them more easily afterwards.

If you still want to do this with trigger then you should rethink your test scenario. Your trigger runs for every insert and update. But to be able to change your triggered records you need to use **before** not after. If you use after then you need to update this records which will cause trigger to trigger again aaannnd we have triggerception after this point. Let's say you fix this too. Then your test class should look like this.

```
@isTest
public class TestCommissionUpdate{
    static testmethod void insertOpportunity(){

    Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
    newOpp.Name = 'test opp';
    newOpp.Type = 'New Business';
    newOpp.CloseDate = date.today();
    newOpp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    newOpp.LeadSource = 'Self Generated';
    newOpp.Trade_Show_Name__c = 'Fake Trade Show';
    newOpp.City__c = 'Fake City';
    newOpp.State__c ='Fake State';
    newOpp.Subtotal__c = 660.00;
    newOpp.Tax__c = 39.60;
    newOpp.Purchases__c = 384;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c  = 0;
    insert newOpp;   
    system.assertEquals(0, newOpp.Commission_Real__c); //and assert correct value each time
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 35;
    update newOpp;

    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 40;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 45;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 50;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 60;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 70;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 80;
    update newOpp;
    //test for not Self Generated LeadSource
    newOpp.LeadSource= 'Web';
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 0;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 35;
    update newOpp;
     newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 40;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 45;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 50;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 60;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 70;
    update newOpp;
    newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c = 80;
    update newOpp;
    }
}
```

Your trigger code should look like this;

```
trigger CommissionUpdate on Opportunity (before update, before insert) {
    for(Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new){
        if(newOpp.LeadSource.equals('Self Generated')){
            if(newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=0 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <35){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 0;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=35 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c < 40){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 5;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 8;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=50 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <60){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 11;    
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=60 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <70){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 12;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=70){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 13;         
            }

      }else{
             if(newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=0 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <35){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 0;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=35 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c < 40){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 2;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=40 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <50){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 3.5;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=50 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <60){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 5.5;    
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=60 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <70){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 6.5;
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >=70 && newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c <80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 7;         
            }else if (newOpp.Mark_Up_Real__c >80){
                    newOpp.Commission_Real__c = 7.5; 
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used your code and I had to make some small modifications but it works however, I need the Mark_Up__Real__c field as a formula, so when testing the trigger my test class always fails. Is there a work around that? Would I have to use a try and catch clause in the test class?